# Why is Aptana Studio 3 hiding Javascript parameters(?)

Tags: javascript, aptana

Here is some of the map code as Aptana displays it in the editor:

```
<area href="#" alt="" shape="rect" coords="18, 6, 104, 26" onMouseover="        (event,       [1])" onMouseout="             ()">
<area href="#" alt="" shape="rect" coords="18, 40, 101, 60" onMouseover="        (event,        [0])" onMouseout="             ()">`
```

onMouseover, event, & onMouseout are all blanked out. They are only visible if I select that code. Is there a setting somewhere that will change this? I couldn't find one. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a font color setting has it the same color as your background; `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Aptana Studio -> Themes` i believe is where you can change the syntax colors

Comment: couldn't find a specific color setting, but by changing from the default theme to another one it allowed the blanked-out text to become visible. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.